# Redmine "Issue priorities" reordering

Tags: redmine

In a brand new installation of Redmine 3.4.2.stable (under Centos7/Passenger/NginX, if that matters; I can give the whole setup, if requested) I added two more "Issue priorities": "Postponed" and "Background" which should be lower than "Low".

This is how I see the page after creation ("Postponed" and "Background" have highest priority):

[image: "natural" sort]

I can reorder priorities as follows:

[image: required sort order]

... but I see no way to save the change and, unsurprisingly, if I reload the page order returns back to the original one.

Also in "Issues" page, when sorting according to Priority, Redmine shows "Background" at top.

What am I missing?

What should I check?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a known bug fixed in v:3.4.3.

The bug report is [here](http://www.redmine.org/issues/26564) and the fix is a trivial one-liner:

```
diff --git a/app/controllers/enumerations_controller.rb b/app/controllers/enumerations_controller.rb
index 985e988bc..e5e3cc3de 100644
--- a/app/controllers/enumerations_controller.rb
+++ b/app/controllers/enumerations_controller.rb
@@ -105,6 +105,6 @@ class EnumerationsController < ApplicationController

   def enumeration_params
     # can't require enumeration on #new action
-    params.permit(:enumeration => [:name, :active, :is_default])[:enumeration]
+    params.permit(:enumeration => [:name, :active, :is_default, :position])[:enumeration]
   end
 end
```

Thanks to "Mischa The Evil" for pointing me in the right direction.